# What kind of Quote is this?

Tags: cipher

Give the name of the person who said these amazing words...

> pbzzbafraf vf abg jung lbh frr vasebag bs lbhe rlrf vgf n tvsg bs frrvat jungf vasebag bs bguref rlr

Hint:

> This person is a fictional ghost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By ROT13 I get

> commonsens is not what you see infront of your eyes its a gift of seeing whats infront of others eye

That is

> Common sense is not what you see in front of your eyes. Its a gift of seeing what's in front of others eye

This quote is by

> Jason Bourne (courtesy of @Prashant Kumar)

Comment: What's the name of the person?

Comment: Trying to figure out

Comment: @manshu Correct! The person may have a whole lot of movies under his belt.

Comment: @manshu It seems.. Google is unable to find this quote. So I think I should reveal the name of the person whose quote was taken from a poster in my room. It is Jason Bourne.

Comment: @PrashantKumar This quote was not even on the imdb...Thanks for the answer.. :)